# iDevice for Dummies: Can a device be assigned multiple provisions (Personal/Enterprise)?

Tags: xcode, ios

Is it possible to assign multiple provisions to an iDevice? To be honest, I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology, but basically, I'm developing an iPad app for a company and I've only been testing it in the simulator because I don't have a registration to the developer program and they haven't setup their enterprise registration yet either. And I'm sure you all know how limited the simulator is...

I don't really care about the $99 it costs to join, but what I'm worried about is having my iDevices locked permanently to my personal registration and unable to switch back and forth to the enterprise registration.

I'd appreciate it if someone can explain to me how the registrations work. And keep in mind, I'm a dummy. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may provision your device with both the standard and enterprise programs, and install their individual provisioning profiles to build your app with. But you'll have to sign your app differently because the provisioning portal generates different app IDs for your app for each account.

If you'd like to test that provisioning profiles work correctly with different developer program accounts, you can duplicate your existing build configuration profile by Control-clicking your Xcode project, choosing **Get Info**, going to the **Configurations** tab and duplicating a configuration. Then sign one configuration against your standard provisioning profile, and sign the other against the enterprise provisioning profile (go to the **Build** tab and look under the **Code Signing** section). Once ready to test your app on your iPad, pick and build as necessary.

Comment: Man, that is one ridiculously long process to get an app on an iDevice just to *test*... And the code signing feels like an attempt to see if mud will stick to walls...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A device can have many different provisions installed from many different developers, either or both enterprise and personal (or occasionally special ones from Apple).

In summary, when you sign up for and are accepted into a paid iOS developer program, you can create and download 2 certificates, then you can download provisions (using those certificates and your device UDIDs and your app IDs), then Xcode, using those certificates and provisions, can build and sign apps that will run on any devices with those UDIDs and with those provisions installed.