# Can I use the same iDevice with multiple developer accounts?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iDevice for Dummies: Can a device be assigned multiple provisions (Personal/Enterprise)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846248/idevice-for-dummies-can-a-device-be-assigned-multiple-provisions-personal-ente)

I'm a freelancer developing iOS apps mostly in AIR. I just bought an iPad to be able to compile and test on ios devices.
My problem is the following: the apps I make will be published and tested with my client's apple accounts. Will this pose a problem for apple?

In other words, can a the same iDevice linked to multiple apple dev accounts(possibly 15+)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You'll create a provisioning profile for each. You can have many provisioning profiles on a single device.